# How to solve integrals which involves Gaussian and binomial such as $(1-x^2)^n e^{-\beta(x-\mu)^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gaussian-integral, error-function

I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^n e^{-\beta(x-\mu)^2}dx$$
where $x\in[-1,1]$, $\{\beta,\mu\}\in \mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\beta >0$.

I tried to solve it through expanding $(1-x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k}$ by binomial expantion then by solving the integrals with the form $$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2k} e^{-\beta(x-\mu)^2}dx$$ where k=0, 1, 2, ... n, but i could not find the solution, in book "[Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, EH II 195(31)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123849335/table-of-integrals-series-and-products)" I could only found the solution for the integral with limits fron $-\infty $ to $\infty$ as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n} e^{-(x-\mu)^2}dx=(2i)^{-n}H_n(i\mu),$$ which does not help.
I tried to solve $\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2k} e^{-\beta(x-\mu)^2}dx$ by applying the integration by parts 2k times and i got the following solution $$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2k} e^{-\beta(x-\mu)^2}dx=\frac{1}{\beta^{k+1}}\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}X^{2k} e^{-(X-\nu)^2}dX=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\beta^{k+1}}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{2k}(-1)^jX^{2k^{(j)}}I^j(erfc(X-\nu))\right]_{-\beta}^{\beta}$$ where
$X^{2k^{(j)}}$ is the $j^{th}$ derivative of $X^{2k}$ and $I^j(erfc(X-\nu))$ is the $j^{th}$ indefinite integral of $erfc(X-\nu)$, which is different that $i^n erfc(z)$ at [DLMF 7.18.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.18#E12), which is defined for integral from $z$ to $\infty$ hòw to get a form for
$$I^j(erfc(X-\nu))=\left(\int\left(\int..._j...\left(\int erfc(X-\nu)dx \right)..._j...dx\right) dx\right) $$
I also checked the integral representation of the conflouent hypergeometric functions [M(a,b,z)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [U(a,b,z)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) but i could not reach a similar forms.

Comment: There are no closed form solutions for those integrals from $-1$ to $1$. Just integrating the Gaussian PDF from $-1$ to $1$ is unknown, the error function is defined to be the answer to such PDF integration. If you can get an answer in terms of the error function then you are doing pretty well.

Comment: Although I did not try a formal proof, looking at the results for $n$ in the set {$1,2,3,4$}, one can probably prove by integration by parts (or the generating function below), that the indefinite integral is of the form $P_n(\beta,\mu,x) e^{-\beta  (x-\mu )^2} + Q_n(\beta,\mu,x)\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\beta }
   (x-\mu )\right)$ where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are multivariate polynomials. Also by integration by parts one might find a recurrence relationship for the $P_n$ and $Q_n$. The question is then whether these polynomials can be mapped to a known recurrence formula for multivariate polynomials.

Comment: If the task at the end is to compute the result numerically then I imagine that applying the recurrence formula on numerical values for the parameters can be rather fast. Symbolic expressions for the polynomials can be heavy on memory and might be less efficient than a numerical recurrence formula unless they are placed in Horner form. Even then, they can still be heavy on memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exponential generating function of your sequence of integrals is

$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n e^{-\beta (x-\mu)^2}\; dx
&= \int_{-1}^1 e^{z(1-x^2) -\beta (x-\mu)^2}\; dx\cr
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4(\beta+z)}} e^{z - \beta z \mu^2/(\beta+z)} \left( \text{erf}\left(\frac{\beta \mu + \beta + z}{\sqrt{\beta+z}}\right)+ \text{erf}\left(\frac{-\beta \mu + \beta + z}{\sqrt{\beta+z}}\right)\right) }$$

EDIT:
The term for $n$ is the $n$'th derivative of the exponential generating function evaluated at $z=0$.  Unfortunately that's going to be a very complicated expression even for $n=10$.  However, there are other things you can do with it.  For example, you can get a linear recurrence relation:

$$ \beta^2 a(n+3) + (2 \beta \mu^2 - 2 \beta + 4 n + 9) \beta a(n+2) + (n+2)(n+1) (2 n - 4 \beta + 3) a(n+1) - 2 (n+2)(n+1) a(n) = 0 $$

where $a(n)$ is your integral.

Comment: @Ropet Thank you, excuse my shallow knowleadge, my main goal is to solve this integral for certain n, for example $n=10, 100, 1000, ...$, Could you please explain for me how can this generating function be used to find the integral at such values, especially that i am expecting a result as a function in $n$.